# Store annotation on map using state restoration

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I'm adding an annotation at the user position in my viewDidLoad and try store that annotation using state restoration. 
I want the annotation to stay there even if the app gets terminated in the background.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
...

self.annotationregion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapview.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, self.mapview.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude), MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5));


self.parkinglocation = [[SWAnnotation alloc] init];
self.parkinglocation.title = @"Here it is!";
self.parkinglocation.coordinate = self.annotationregion.center;
[self.mapview addAnnotation:self.parkinglocation];

NSLog(@"userlocation: %@", self.mapview.userLocation);

NSNumber *longitudeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.annotationregion.center.longitude];
NSNumber *latitudeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.annotationregion.center.latitude];
self.coordinateArray = @[latitudeNumber,longitudeNumber];

}

 -(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
...
[coder encodeObject:self.coordinateArray forKey:@"CoordinateArray"];
}


-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
...

NSArray *coordinateArray = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"CoordinateArray"];
self.annotationregion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinateArray[0] doubleValue], [coordinateArray[1] doubleValue]), MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.5,1.5));
self.parkinglocation = [[SWAnnotation alloc] init];
self.parkinglocation.title = @"tata!";
self.parkinglocation.coordinate = self.annotationregion.center;
[self.mapview addAnnotation:self.parkinglocation];
}
```

Note, in the initial viewDidLoad annotation I use the title "Here it is!" and in the decodeRestorableStateWithCoder annotation I use the title "tata!" just to see which one it's showing me at the moment.

Now, this seems to work when the app gets terminated for the first time in the background. The app starts back up and has an annotation with the new title "tata!" at the right position.
The second time it gets terminated in the background and then gets started back up it shows me an annotation with the initial title of "Here it is!" off the coast of Africa, which of course is not my position...
Sooo I'm getting frustrated, what am I missing?

Comment: `mapview.userLocation` is not guaranteed to be available and ready in `viewDidLoad`.  You should only read it from the map view delegate method `didUpdateUserLocation`.  Outside of that delegate method (to be safe, even in the delegate method), you have to check if `mapview.userLocation.location` is `nil` before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that when you encode the state you actually encode `self.coordinateArray`, but when you restore you use a local variable `NSArray *coordinateArray` to restore.
So when your app will encode again later, your `self.coordinateArray` would be nil.

I think you should set `[self setCoordinateArray: coordinateArray];` just after `NSArray *coordinateArray = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"CoordinateArray"];`